# Getting a random string from a random array from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I've been strugling with this issue for a week and I cannot find a solution anywhere. Hope someone can help. I have a set of string arrays in strings.xml. It's a language app where each level has 10 words. In "training", I want to get words from every level and mix them randomly. Each level is onw string-array in strings.xml.Since I want to get 10 words from several random levels, I have to pick random strings from random string arrays.

```
int i = 0;
List<String> myWords;
String [] arrayListTraining;
```

// I declared these in mainactivity.
// the following is placed inside onCreate

```
while (i < 10) {

            int randomLevel = randXev.nextInt(numbeerOfLevels);
            String rutaStringsResposta = "Level" + randomLevel;
            int idRespsotes = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(rutaStringsResposta, "array", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            arrayListTraining = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(idRespsotes);
            String randomStr = arrayListTraining[new Random().nextInt(arrayListTraining.length)];
            myWords.add(randomStr);
            i++;
        }
```

The code works well, but as soon as i add something to myWords (a list) the app crashes. arrayListTraining is a string [] but i've tried also as a list with no success.

Thank you very much!

since my emulator isn't working and I'm using a usb device, this is the only error log I could find, but i don't think it's related:

12-27 14:31:46.704 6875-6875/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:46.931 6881-6881/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:46.994 6886-6886/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.056 6890-6890/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.142 6894-6894/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.206 6898-6898/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.269 6902-6902/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.331 6906-6906/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.369 3165-3486/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2412 BSSID=88:03:55:9e:65:bd RSSI=-46 "Orange-65BB"WPA_PSK
12-27 14:31:47.395 6910-6910/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.468 6914-6914/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
12-27 14:31:47.530 6918-6918/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.root.exercicis-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied

Comment: can you post your error logs

Comment: please provide error logs and more part of your code

Comment: In particular, your code snippet doesn't show the creation of several variables (`myWords`, `i`, `arrayListTraining`) that could be causing this problem.

Comment: My emulator isn't working and I cannot show you the error log for some reason.  I'll edit the post with the creation of the variables

Comment: It would be easier to have a table in a database, with an "id", a "level" and a "string" fields. Then it would be very easy to generate a random nuber for level, take the strings matching that level and then picking a random string from that subset - I'm pretty sure it can be done with a single query.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint before you add an item to the myWords and see what the item is?